# Websphere Portal 8 add minimize and maximize buttons to skin

Tags: themes, skin, websphere-portal

I have a requirement to add maximize, minimize and restore buttons to a portlet skin created in a custom theme based on the Websphere Portal 8 theme. Currently the skin generates a pull down context menu with these.

This used to be easy in version 6.1.5 and previous using portal tags, but versions 7 and 8  are substantially different and use json and reams of javascript to populate the menus and I'm unclear how and where the urls are generated for these actions. The information in the infocentre is unclear to say the least!

Does anybody know how to do create urls to minimize and maximize portlets from the skin?

Answer (score 2):

It seems I found way to maximize and minimize portlet on page, but you need to try

When you press context menu buttom portal return json with actions, like this

```
    {
      "type":"Menuitem",
      "actionUrl":"?uri=op:ibm.portal.operations.changeWindowState(%257B%2522windowState%2522%253A%2522normal%2522%252C%2522resourceURI%2522%253A%2522pm%253Aoid%253AZ7_MP8E1O42IGIT10IF8IR80N1052%2540oid%253AZ6_MP8E1O42IGIT10IF8IR80N10C0%2522%257D)",
      "moduleArgs":"windowState=normal",
      "visibilityFn":"wptheme.isValidOp",
      "id":"ibm.portal.operations.changeWindowState",
      "actionHttpMethod":"GET",
      "title":{
         "lang":"en",
         "value":"Restore"
      },
      "description":{
         "lang":"en",
         "value":"Restore"
      },
      "metadata":{
         "windowState":"normal",
         "wid":"Z7_MP8E1O42IGIT10IF8IR80N1052"
      }
   },
```

When you press portelt menu action, maximized for example, link you submit like this

```
http://yuorhost:10039/wps/myportal/yourpage/!ut/p/b1/hdDLDoJADAXQT2ohyGOJgDAKaAhEmI0ZdcRRGEgkJPL1onELdH1uc1ugkAOVrBcl60QjWQUFFNQ4RQfTU_aaSnySKkg2JklMjBVcqZBXvGSXN6SyjiCrhRS1GPj1u4jqk0EHR1CMACfGxqX8EeiPOL4daEaI6B8MC4m7tjCKCfp7fQlofzDXYbbFToE4aGoOW6Bl1ZzHf41XPbV71ttAXx3rOORNyyW01WMI9cS7uaH9AdoyOYI!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/?uri=op:ibm.portal.operations.changeWindowState(%257B%2522windowState%2522%253A%2522maximized%2522%252C%2522resourceURI%2522%253A%2522pm%253Aoid%253AZ7_MP8E1O42IGIT10IF8IR80N1052%2540oid%253AZ6_MP8E1O42IGIT10IF8IR80N10C0%2522%257D)
```

you interested with this part

```
?uri=op:ibm.portal.operations.changeWindowState(%257B%2522windowState%2522%253A%2522maximized%2522%252C%2522resourceURI%2522%253A%2522pm%253Aoid%253AZ7_MP8E1O42IGIT10IF8IR80N1052%2540oid%253AZ6_MP8E1O42IGIT10IF8IR80N10C0%2522%257D)
```

this is action uri from json above. If you decode this string twice with this for example (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) you'll get

```
{"windowState":"maximized","resourceURI":"pm:oid:Z7_MP8E1O42IGIT10IF8IR80N1052@oid:Z6_MP8E1O42IGIT10IF8IR80N10C0"}
```

pm:oid: = portlet id, oid: = page id.

Thus to mazimize\minimize portlet you need construct link\send get on current page with decoded parameters, another actions you can see from json.

Also I beleive to gets this worked you need include portal page builder theme javascript and other things in your custom theme.

Hope this helps